# Adding Items To A ListView From A Different Thread? (Cross-thread operation not valid)

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I'm trying to add items to a list view in a different thread than it was created in and am getting a cross-thread error.  How can I make this element accessible in other threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use property control: InvokeRequired - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28VS.80%29.aspx

```
private delegate void AddItemCallback(object o);

private void AddItem(object o)
{
    if (this.listView.InvokeRequired)
    {
        AddItemCallback d = new AddItemCallback(AddItem);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { o });
    }
    else
    {
        // code that adds item to listView (in this case $o)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I add this code where my listview is created or where I want to add to my listview?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Task` that does the update, scheduled to the UI using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997394.aspx

The advantage to this approach over `Control.Invoke` is that it will work in WPF, Silverlight, *or* Windows Forms, whereas `Control.Invoke` is Windows Forms-only.

P.S. If you're not on .NET 4.0 yet, then `Task` and `TaskScheduler` are available in the [Rx library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx).